# Error when typing a var as a Function in TSX

Tags: typescript, tsx

I'm new to TS. I'm getting no error with this code:

```
interface Props {
  active: boolean
  error: any // unknown
  input: any // unknown
  onActivate: Function
  onKeyUp: Function
  onSelect: Function
  onUpdate: Function
  readonly: boolean
  selected: boolean
  value: string
}
```

However here, I get an error that reads:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Function'.ts(2451)
```

for each and every declaration of `Function`:

```
const EditableCell: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const {
    input: any,
    value: string,
    selected: Function,
    active: boolean
    onSelect: Function,
    onActivate: Function,
    onUpdate: Function
  } = props
```

BTW, these two code blocks immediately follow one another

Comment: You're not *typing* the props when you destructure them, you're *renaming* them. It's not TypeScript there, just JavaScript. Also they already have types from the function definition, there's no need to repeat them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove type assignments while destructuring props.

```js
const {
  active,
  error, // unknown
  input, // unknown
  onActivate,
  onKeyUp,
  onSelect,
  onUpdate,
  readonly,
  selected,
  value
} = props
```

### Caution -

### **Do not use any and Function type, use proper types instead of them!**

Comment: Can I ask you for more of an explanation, or a link to a site about the Function type. I don't really know what to do for it

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v3.8.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md